# Custom PHP Session Management

Tags: php, session, environment-variables, session-variables

I'm currently switching from PHP's built-in session management based on the filesystem on the server and stuff like `$_SESSION` and `session_start()` to my own approach (I know there are frameworks out there like symfony etc., but my application will most likely do the same of the very basic stuff and no more is needed, so it's not necessary in my point of view to rely on an extension for this).

I'm simply planning on using the traditional session management approach ([source](https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/)):[image]

To use this approach efficiently, I was looking for a way in PHP to pass data to a variable that lies in a scope that is available for all callbacks called during runtime, but still somewhat scoped / protected. Just like `$_SESSION` or any other superglobal, but additionally fulfilling the following criteria:

- Data / Array key collision chances must be minimal; so the variable is ideally empty by default
- The used variable should not be linked to any additional storage system, such as `$_SESSION` is tied to the server's filesystem (or whatever you specify in your session handler)
- The used variable should exclusively be used for that, only be available for the calling script, and die after the runtime of the script

Considering all of this, I am currently thinking of using something like `$_ENV[prefix_udata]`, populated with the data gathered from step 4a of the image from each request. This would avoid that I would need to add extra code or an extra parameter to all of my callbacks by simply replacing stuff like `$_SESSION['uid']` with `$_ENV['uid']` and so on.

I just wanted to double-check that `$_ENV` is not tied to external storage systems, is exclusively available on runtime, and exclusively to the running request. My research let me conclude that that's the case; but better double-check..?

Comment: I assume you have considered [implementing a custom session handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php) to *store* the session differently, rather than re-implementing the whole thing yourself?

Comment: "The used variable should exclusively be used for that, only be available for the calling script, and die after the runtime of the script" But that's not a session?

Comment: @IMSoP sure thing, the problem is that these still rely on stuff like `session_start()`, the filesystem, etc. (which you can of course all override too, but if you override it all entirely, why not directly build it..) And due to many issues I'm having with that, how PHP generates session IDs, how sessions are safely destroyed, IDs regenerated etc.; rather build my own thing directly..

Comment: @ceejayoz which is the core reason for the requirement of the above-mentioned for this project; I'm building a REST API that must be compatible with mobile app frameworks too, so I cannot really rely on fully stateful sessions as PHP uses them.

Comment: @DevelJoe Generally, the whole point of a custom session handler is to store the session *somewhere other than* the disk. But if you have additional changes you want to make, that's fine, I just wanted to check you weren't reinventing the wheel unnecessarily.

Comment: @IMSoP Yup I get you, I thought of many different models and possibilities with the default handler adapted, before deciding to implement my own, precisely for the reason you mention. But cheers!

Comment: @ceejayoz I feel you misunderstood an important aspect. The session, together with its expiry and data, is actually persisting on the DB as long as needed, according to the image above. My question refers to the variable that I should use to automatically make all of my session data, retrieved from the DB via 4a, available to all class and functions called in a script. The question is NOT about the storage of the session data, which should of course persist across multiple requests...

Comment: "I'm building a REST API that must be compatible with mobile app frameworks too, so I cannot really rely on fully stateful sessions as PHP uses them." Have you considered something like JWT, which is built for that scenario?

Comment: @ceejayoz You're not really recommending to use JWT for session management, right? If you do, I encourage you to have a read through http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/, https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/

Comment: @DevelJoe I'm aware of the issues with JWT; you'll note that the Redis articles includes the *fixes* to these issues (a token blacklist, generally stored somewhere like Redis itself, and database lookups rather than filling the JWT with a bunch of stale data). I'm also aware of the issues "Not invented here syndrome" has, which you seem to have fallen victim to.

Comment: And maintaining a token blacklist renders JWT just as stateful, additionally adding crypto-steps for en- and decryption, etc. Maybe opinion-based, I've actually carefull researched JWT and almost decided on using it, until reading the linked and other articles, which rendered its benefits completely obsolete for my usecase. And I guess I'd never use it for secure and fast session management. But anyway, I rather wonder about the questions I formulated about `$_ENV` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create your own [superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), and each of them has a defined purpose - `$_ENV` is for values passed from the "environment" of the script, such as information provided by the web server. It doesn't seem like a good idea to re-use one for a different purpose, just to take advantage of its special scoping rules.

However, you can create [normal global variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), and access them either using the `global` keyword or via [the `$GLOBALS` superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).

So if you make a global variable called `$my_session_array`, you can simply replace all code like `$_SESSION['foo']` with `$GLOBALS['my_session_array']['foo']`, and there's no need to abuse superglobals intended for other purposes.

---

Another alternative would be to use a [static property on a class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). Like a global variable, a public static property can be accessed from anywhere within the request.

For example if you define this:

```
class MySession {
    public static $sessionData = [];
}
```

Then you could replace `$_SESSION['foo']` with `MySession::$sessionData['foo']`.

---

Both approaches have all the problems associated with shared global state - code using it is generally harder to test and debug than code that is defined in terms of explicit inputs and outputs.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather use `$_ENV` ? Or is there a reason why you advise against that? I just want to avoid to add anything, really anything at all, to the global scope

Comment: @DevelJoe updated with more notes and another suggestion

Comment: Cheers! The static variables won't work, as my application code sometimes uses methods from like 5 different classes in one run, so that would be too much extra work. I also consider session data like an "external environment" to my REST calls, hence my thoughts. But than you can confirm that `$_ENV` actually meets my 3 criteria mentioned above?

Comment: I totally agree with the purpose you mention for `$_ENV`, but given all the context I've provided you with; I feel it's better to rely on `$_ENV` rather than `$_GLOBAL`; just because, imho, `$_GLOBAL` is more likely in being populated by other stuff, worst case even external packages that have been developed by newbies who generally write to the global scope or similar... How would you think in that sense? Just curious, and thx for the help; much appreciated.

Comment: @DevelJoe I think you've misunderstood my suggestion about a static property - there's no need for it to be associated with any of your existing classes, or to be in more than one place, it's just a place to put the data, just as $GLOBALS or $_ENV would be. Ignoring the background, your requirements are really very simple "store some global state somewhere". A global variable, a key in a superglobal, or a static property will all achieve that, and **I think using a superglobal is the worst of the three**, and can not see any advantage to doing so.

Comment: indeed completely misunderstood you. And given that I am implementing my whole session logic with a custom class anyway, your approach with a class makes absolute sense (I have to admit, I'm feeling somewhat stupid rn^^) cheers!

Comment: Well no, actually using this approach you'd still need to provide an extra parameter to every callback using `$_SESSION`. The advantage of using a superglobal is that you could do a search replace and that's it, no need to add the extra parameter to your callbacks.

Comment: @DevelJoe What extra parameter? Find "$_SESSION", replace with "MySession::$sessionData". Done.

Comment: Ok yes meaning I have to use the class only as the scope wrapper, and instead of a constructor code exclusively static functions used to CRUD sessions, whereas initiating means populating the public static variable. That's what you mean I guess?

Comment: @DevelJoe However you were planning to populate `$_ENV`, use that to populate the static array instead. It's just another globally-accessible array.

Comment: Yup got it, struggled with the thus consequent omission of a proper constructor, but makes total sense to do the custom session class with only statics for this purpose. Cheers once again!